# User rank based on cumulative rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1, rank

**UPDATE:**
Full table schema and data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jT3Mfwd1BJ8GrsBxxPDC8M/1

Table structure (some fields are hidden):

```
+---------+---------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| user_id | kind_id | country_id | province_id | value | score |
+---------+---------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
|       1 |     201 |          1 |           1 |     1 |     5 |
|       1 |     102 |          1 |           1 |    31 |   155 |
|       1 |     201 |          1 |           1 |     6 |    30 |
|       1 |     109 |          1 |           1 |    33 |   165 |
|       2 |     202 |          1 |           4 |    76 |   380 |
|       2 |     201 |          1 |           4 |     5 |    25 |
|       2 |     209 |          1 |           4 |     9 |    45 |
|       2 |     302 |          1 |           4 |     8 |    40 |
|       2 |     201 |          1 |           4 |    14 |    70 |
|       3 |     201 |          1 |           9 |     7 |    35 |
|       3 |     201 |          1 |           9 |     9 |    45 |
|       3 |     201 |          1 |           9 |     2 |    10 |
|       3 |     201 |          1 |           9 |     5 |    25 |
|       3 |     201 |          1 |           9 |     7 |    35 |
|     ... |     ... |        ... |         ... |   ... |   ... |
+---------+---------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

Rank is calculated based on sum of `score` of user's activities.
I saw many questions here and on Stackoverflow but my problem is more complex.

I need 3 rank values per user: global, country (for users in same country), province (same as country). For example a rank value for user 1 may be like this `{"global": 9, "country": 3, "province": 1}`. I do not need rank of all users but for one individual user.

I tried a dozen queries but can't calculate this three with one query. or, at least, three clean and efficient queries.

I will cache the result for some time, but still efficiency is important since the activities table contains many records and will grow as time passes.

How can I do this?

> Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

Comment: Which version of MariaDB or MYSQL do you use?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Its `Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I can also change that to `MySQL 5.7.x` if needed. But not `8.x`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please replace your sample table with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (or create a fiddle) and post the result based on that data with detailed explaination how it is calculated. PS. Rank calculations MUST have some ordering - do not forget to specify it.

Comment: @Akina I Updated my question with a link to the fiddle. Order is defined in the question: the user with biggest `SUM(score)` has the best rank (1) and so on... AND there are contexts such as global, country and province.

Comment: Can a user have activities in different countries / provinces?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ oops... it was browser lag.

Comment: *I Updated my question with a link to the fiddle.* Your fiddle contains DDL and sample data. Your fiddle do not contain (in comment `/* */` form) desured output for this sample data. And (because CTE and window functions are preferred) specify your server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window ranking functions. I used `RANK()` but you could as well use `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` depending on what you want to happen on ties.

Unfortunately, [window functions have been introduced in MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/), so you'll have to upgrade from 10.1, in order to use this:

```
SELECT
    user_id, country_id, province_id,
    SUM(score) AS total_score,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC)
      AS rank_total,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id
                 ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC)
      AS rank_country,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, province_id
                 ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC)
      AS rank_province
FROM activities 
GROUP BY 
    country_id, province_id, user_id
ORDER BY 
    rank_total ;
```

Tested at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b7c28aa67cb52a83ac87efb260e50405)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question, but you may benefit from a rollup. MySQL have there own version of grouping sets that look like:

```
SELECT country_id
     , province_id
     , user_id
     , SUM(score) AS total_score 
FROM activities 
GROUP BY country_id, province_id, user_id
WITH ROLLUP;
```

null in user_id column means an aggregation, dito för province_id. I.e.

```
1   null    null    64390
```

is the total for country_id = 1